# Association within the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Company. Companies consists of headquarters and branch_offices. They have exactly the same attributes (and won't change). Headquarters can have many branch_offices (optional association). Branch_offices belongs_to headquarter.

I would like to show the association in the API as follows (Note: some data removed as not relevant):

"data": {
"id": "607424",
"type": "companies",
"attributes": {
"commerce_register_data": {
"uid": "US462745827168",
"name": "Big Company Ltd",
},

"branch_offices": [
{
"uid": "US4852847292",
"name": "Big Company Ltd, branch_office Chicago",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"legal_form": {
"id": 9,
"name": {
"en": "Branch",
},
"short_name": {
"en": "Bran",
}
},

How can the relationship between headquarter and branch_offices shown? I came up with this thoughts after some research:

1. Two models: Headquarter and Branch_office

- makes code much more complicated without additional benefit

2. Query because the name follows the pattern: Some Company Name Ltd., branch_office City

- Slow performance and prone to errors

3. One additional model Branch with foreign keys of companies
   seems to complicated
4. Association within the same model, which I believe is possible according to my research (although I have never used it)
5. one additional column headquarter_id to branch_offices to Model Company

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

class Company < ApplicationRecord
has_many :branch_offices, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "headquarter_id"
belongs_to :headquarter, class_name: "Company", optional: true
end

eg:

branch_office = Company.find_by(name: "Big Company Ltd, branch_office Chicago")
headquarter = branch_office.headquarter

headquarter = Company.find_by(name: "Big Company Ltd")
branch_offices = headquarter.branch_offices

Comment: Thanks, then I will go with this option (4).

Answer (score 0):

See in Rails documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

You actually need a self join to represent this hierarchy.

Even if either have additional attributes at a later point you can add another table for those attributes later keeping th association clean.